# Code Coverage VSMDI on Visual Studio 2012 says "There is no test with specified Id"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, test-explorer

I have a solution that is still using VSMDI files.

Running tests are still fine, but when I try to Analyze Code Coverage on the selected test, It shows "Empty results generated".

Looking at the Output Log from Tests, it says
"There is no test with specified Id {09c3a333-1a28-27bf-2d79-8f6aa8fe5e3a}."

From what I see, the Id mentioned is the Test Id in VSMDI file

Does anybody why this happen ?